# Running CLI on web hosting

Tags: web-hosting

I currently have a hosting around from [Solid Shell Security](http://solidshellsecurity.com) and one from [Blue Host](http://bluehost.com) (both great web hosts not trying to cut them down here) and I can't seem to run CLI applications on either of them. Is this normal for shared hosting? Do I need a dedicated server?

Comment: Whats the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have SSH then you should be able to run CLI applications from there.

Comment: Yep, that was it. SolidShellSecurity is setting me up now and I've sent in e-mail to BlueHost so all is going well!!! :D

Comment: Also depending on your account privileges (normally only root can install packages) and the libraries installed you might not be able to run your CLI app.